# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration' when run on Docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I created spring boot project, it works well if I run locally. However, when I dockerize this app and run it inside Docker container. The problems occurs with `Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration'`

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
COPY target/app-*.jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Errors:

```
2018-08-29 03:56:06.093  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'partyPlusUserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'partyPlusUserDetailsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/datnt/pplus/service/user/PartyPlusUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#71238fc2' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#71238fc2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2018-08-29 03:56:06.099  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-29 03:56:06.140  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issues?

Comment: Do you have any non standard Hibernate/data source configuration? Post your configuration classes.

Comment: There are no more configuration related to Hibernate/datasource

Comment: Are you sure you have all the dependencies in classpath?

Comment: I am sure about it because I can run on local machine, it works perfectly. The database url is from remote, not docker, I used the physical IP.

Comment: How do you run it on local machine? Does it work if you run it via `java -jar app.jar` locally?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I use docker run properly

Comment: I'm not talking about running it in docker. Y said  that it works if you run it locally, but it doesn't work if you run it in docker. **How do you run it locally?** What is the command? How does it differ from the one you use in docker?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota: I ran java -jar like you said

Comment: @DatNguyen were you able to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: @Vastlik: the problem has not been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "application.properties" and place it in the folder "src/main/resources"